# How to create a dynamic chart in Google Apps Script UI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am looking to replicate the effect that you see in this Google I/O video at the 24m55s of this video (http://youtu.be/38H7WpsTD0M?t=24m55s).

Does anyone know how this is done? The goal is to have an Apps Script webApp that shows a dynamic bar chart where its values change (and animate) upon changing of the values of the underlying spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the link to this video, it was really interresting and somehow I didn't notice it...

That said, this shows a development in the very specific context of the new form edition environment and if I refer to what they say in [the doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app?hl=fr-FR) and appears in the video as well :

`FormApp.getUi()` *Returns an instance of the form editor's user-interface environment that allows the script to add features like menus, dialogs, and sidebars. A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open form editor (not the view that a respondent sees), and only if the script is container-bound to the form.*

And there are indeed triggers to know when a form has been submitted but these are only able to interact with the UI if the script is container-bounded in the form editor itself.
A user interface can indeed be build in the form editor and called by something like : `FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface)` and from there you will get the interactivity you are asking for but not from a standalone webapp.

Is that how you are developing it ? from what I read in you question I can't be sure.

Also were you able to find the code they used at Google I/O for their quizz demo ? I didn't look for it yet but I'm sure it would be truly interesting to analyze. Let us know if you did and feel free to post the link.

Comment: Thanks Serge. Unfortunately I still have not found the code for the quiz demo :(. 
In regards to your question about my app, I am not developing it like this (container bound), I'm developing a standalone app and that's why I'm really struggling to get the dynamic chart working. I did however stumbled upon this [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object)) which explains that a sidebar can use an `HtmlOutput` too. Maybe the UI is html & making asynchronous callbacks using the google.script API for `HtmlService` instead of server handlers for `UiApp`.