# Google Apps Script, fastest way to retrieve data from external spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to load data from multiple spreadsheets(~100) into a single spreadsheet, however when I try to do this my script times out. It appears that opening each spreadsheet takes a long time. Is there any way I can speed this up or a work around?

Here's what I use to open each spreadsheet

```
// We set the current spreadsheet to master and get the current date.
var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var masterSheet = master.getSheetByName('Master');
var users = master.getEditors();
var today = new Date();

// Adds the menu to the spreadsheet
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Update Data",
    functionName : "retrievePartnerData"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Submissions Menu", entries);
};


// First we get all data from the partner sheets
function retrievePartnerData() {

  masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, masterSheet.getLastRow(), masterSheet.getLastColumn()).clear(); //Clear our master sheet aka Sheet All
  masterSheet.hideSheet();

  //Get's Promo Outline from the internal sheet and store it's values in the promoRange array
  var promoRange = master.getSheetByName("Promotional Outline").getRange("A1:Z100").getValues();

  var sheetPartnerArray = [];

  // Row is an array that contaings the url's to the external spreadsheets
  var row = master.getSheetByName('Partner Sheet Collection').getRange("B:B").getValues();

  row.map(function(e){
    if(e[0] != "" && e[0] != "Url"){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(e[0]);

      var studioName = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").getValue();

      //Updates the Promotional Outline sheet in the partner sheet
      var promoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Promotional Outline");   
      promoSheet.getRange("A1:Z100").setValues(promoRange);

      //Hide columns K to Z
      promoSheet.hideColumns(11,4);

      var sheet = ss.getSheets();

      sheet.map(function(f){
        var sheetName = f.getSheetName(); // Retrieves the sheetname of each sheet

        var lastRow = 0;
        if(f.getLastRow() == 1) {
          lastRow = 1;
        } else {
          lastRow = f.getLastRow() - 1;
        }
        var dataRange = f.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, f.getLastColumn());
        var data = dataRange.getValues();

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          if (data[j][0].length != 0 && (data[j][5] > today || data[j][5] == "[Please Enter]")) { // We check if the promo end date is after the current day
            var sheetRow = data[j];
            sheetRow[1] = studioName;
            sheetRow.unshift(sheetName); //Adds the Country to the beginning of the row using the sheet name from spreadsheets 
            sheetPartnerArray.push(sheetRow);
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
  masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetPartnerArray.length , sheetPartnerArray[0].length ).setValues(sheetPartnerArray);
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: How often does this script run? Could you, say, run it once for each sheet on a time-drive trigger five minutes apart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common approach is to set a trigger to restart your Big Job at some time in the future (just beyond the maximum execution time). Then your Big Job does as much as it can (or stops nicely at some logical point), and either gets killed or quietly exits. Either way, it gets restarted shortly after, and resumes its work.

Patt0 has taken this idea to an elegant end, [providing a library](http://patt0.blogspot.ca/2014/01/using-scriptapp-to-process-batches-in.html) that you can add to your script. With a few adaptations, you should be able to turn your `retrievePartnerData()` into a batch job.

Since you have a menu already, and `retrievePartnerData()` involves iterating over many spreadsheets, you have the opportunity to break the barrier another way, by completing each iteration (or better, a set of iterations) in a separate server script instance.

This technique appears in [What happens when I "sleep" in GAS ? (execution time limit workaround)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886550/what-happens-when-i-sleep-in-gas-execution-time-limit-workaround)

And there is something similar in [How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178). In that answer, a UI client uses a timer to repeatedly execute a server function. Here, though, iterations would be work-based, rather than time-based. This client-side function, running in your browser, would keep calling the server until there was no more work to be done:

```
  /**
   * Call the server-side 'serverProcess' function until there's no more work.
   */
  function dispatchWork(){
    if (window.runningProcess) {
    }
    google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(                //<<<< if last call was good
       // After each interval, decide what to do next
       function(workis) {
         if (!workis.done) {             //<<<<< check if we're done
           // There's more work to do, keep going.
           dispatchWork();
         }
         else {
           // All done. Stop timer
           stopTimer();
           $('#start-process').hide();
           $("#final").html(' <h2>Processing complete!</h2>');
         }
       })
     .withFailureHandler(
       function(msg, element) {         //<<<<<< do this if error
         showError(msg, $('#button-bar'));
         element.disabled = false;
       })
     .serverProcess();                  //<<<<< call server function
  };
```

In your case, you first need to refactor `retrievePartnerData()` so it can be called from a client to process a single spreadsheet (or set of them). No doubt you have put considerable time into making that `map` loop work cleanly, and taking it apart will be painful, but it will be worth it.

The following spreadsheet-bound script can be adapted to your use. It consists of a menu item, a simple UI, and scripts on the client (Javascript + jQuery) and server (Google Apps Script), which control the work in intervals.

[image: screenshot]

The control data is in a "SourceSheets" tab, and results will be copied to "Master".

[image: screenshot]

### Code.gs

```js
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

// Adds the menu to the spreadsheet
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Update Data",
    functionName : "updateData"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Big Job", entries);
};

/**
 * Presents UI to user.
 */
function updateData () {
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Conductor")
                                 .setHeight(150)
                                 .setWidth(250)
                                 .setTitle("What 5 minute limit?");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.show(userInterface)
}

/**
 * Called from client, this function performs the server work in
 * intervals. It will exit when processing time has exceeded MAX_INTERVAL,
 * 3.5 minutes. Every time this function exits, the client is provided
 * with the current status object, done=true when the work queue has
 * been emptied.
 *
 * @returns {Object}      Status { done: boolean }
 */
function serverProcess() {
  var MAX_INTERVAL = (3.5 * 60);  // minutes * seconds
  var intervalStart = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);

  // Get persisted work queue, if there is one
  var queueProp = properties.getProperty('work-queue') || '[]';
  var queue = JSON.parse(queueProp);

  if (queue.length == 0) {
    queue = prepareWork();
  }

  // Do the work for this interval, until we're out of time
  while ((Math.round(new Date() / 1000) - intervalStart) < MAX_INTERVAL) {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      var ssID = queue.shift();
      processSheet(ssID);
      properties.setProperty('work-queue', JSON.stringify(queue));
    }
    else break;
  }

  // Report result of this interval to client
  var result = { done : (queue.length == 0) };
  return( result );
}

/**
 * Set up work queue & clear Master sheet, ready to import data from source sheets.
 *
 * @return {String[]}             work queue
 */
function prepareWork() {
  // No work yet, so set up work
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var rowsToDelete = masterSheet.getMaxRows()-1;
  if (rowsToDelete)
    masterSheet.deleteRows(2, rowsToDelete);  //Clear our master sheet aka Sheet All

  // Build work queue
  var queue = [];
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('SourceSheets')      // get all data
               .getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.splice(0,1)[0];                // take headers off it
  var ssIDcol = headers.indexOf('Spreadsheet ID');  // find column with work
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    queue.push(data[i][ssIDcol]);                   // queue up the work
  }
  // Persist the work queue as a scriptProperty
  properties.setProperty('work-queue', JSON.stringify(queue));
  return queue;
}

/**
 * Do whatever work item we need. In this example, we'll import all data from
 * the source sheet and append it to our Master.
 *
 * @param {String}  ssID       Source spreadsheet ID
 */
function processSheet(ssID) {
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master');
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  Utilities.sleep(60000);   // You probably don't want to do this... just wasting time.

  var masterLastRow = masterSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  masterSheet.insertRowsAfter(masterSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastRow());

  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  var destRange = masterSheet.getRange(masterLastRow+1, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length);
  destRange.setValues(sourceData);
}
```

### Conductor.html

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->


<div id="form-div" class="sidebar branding-below">
  <span id="final"></span>
  <form>
    <div class="block" id="button-bar">
      <button class="blue" id="start-process">Start processing</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  Elapsed processing time: <span id="elapsed">--:--:--</span>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  /**
   * On document load, assign click handlers to button(s), add
   * elements that should start hidden (avoids "flashing"), and
   * start polling for document selections.
   */
  $(function() {
    // assign click handler(s)
    $('#start-process').click(startProcess);

  });

  /**
   * Call the server-side 'serverProcess' function until there's no more work.
   */
  function dispatchWork(){
    if (window.runningProcess) {
    }
    google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(
       // After each interval, decide what to do next
       function(workis) {
         if (!workis.done) {
           // There's more work to do, keep going.
           dispatchWork();
         }
         else {
           // All done. Stop timer
           stopTimer();
           $('#start-process').hide();
           $("#final").html(' <h2>Processing complete!</h2>');
         }
       })
     .withFailureHandler(
       function(msg, element) {
         showError(msg, $('#button-bar'));
         element.disabled = false;
       })
     .serverProcess();
  };

  /**
   * Runs a server-side function to retrieve the currently
   * selected text.
   */
  function startProcess() {
    this.disabled = true;  // Disable the button
    $('#error').remove();  // Clear previous error messages, if any
    startTimer();          // Start a work timer, for display to user
    window.runningProcess = true;
    dispatchWork();        // Start our work on the server
  }


  // Timer adapted from http://codingforums.com/javascript-programming/159873-displaying-elapsed-time.html

  /**
    * Kicks off the tick function.
    */
  function startTimer( )
  {
    window.seconds = null;
    window.ticker = null;
    window.seconds = -1;
    window.ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    tick( );
  }

  /**
   * Stop ticking
   */
  function stopTimer()
  {
    clearInterval(window.ticker);
  }

  /*
   * Updates the timer display, between sleeps.
   */
  function tick( )
  {
    ++window.seconds;
    var secs = window.seconds;
    var hrs = Math.floor( secs / 3600 );
    secs %= 3600;
    var mns = Math.floor( secs / 60 );
    secs %= 60;
    var pretty = ( hrs < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hrs
               + ":" + ( mns < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mns
               + ":" + ( secs < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
    $("#elapsed").text(pretty);
  }

  /**
   * Inserts a div that contains an error message after a given element.
   *
   * @param msg The error message to display.
   * @param element The element after which to display the error.
   */
  function showError(msg, element) {
    var div = $('<div id="error" class="error">' + msg + '</div>');
    $(element).after(div);
  }
</script>
```