# GAS - Execution time-out

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that needs to 'setValue' to about 2000 rows.
The problem is, after awhile, I get time-out.

So I'm looking for a solution to split up the job.

I'm thinking of creating a time-based trigger, possibly to start off where the last row or timeout ended. But I can't figure how to get trigger unique ID.

```
function triggerList() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('populateList')
   .timeBased()
   .after(5 * 60 * 1000) // run every 5 mins. Script will time-out.
   .create();

}

function deleteTrigger() {
 // delete the above trigger
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(triggers[i]);
 }
}
```

There is a similar topic on this but i don't quite understand.
[What happens when I "sleep" in GAS ? (execution time limit workaround)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886550/what-happens-when-i-sleep-in-gas-execution-time-limit-workaroun)

Anyone has suggestions, workarounds?

Comment: So you cant set the rows all at once? Why not?

Comment: Without info about how you're setting values (better yet, code), all we can do is guess about why it's slow. A sheet with 2000 rows isn't all that big - a properly optimized script should be able to handle that. Please update your question.

Answer (score 3):

Put all of your data into a two dimensional array first, then set all the values at once.  Each inner array is a row, each element of each inner array is a cell in a new column.

[Set Values Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: This is the solution Google recommends. Your processing time will be cut down by more than 2/3.