# Upper limit of 6 mins on Google App Script execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have switched my Google App Script from default (hidden) GCP instance to my own GCP instance. I was under impression that, after doing this, 6 mins upper limit of App Script execution will no longer be there, but it exists. How can this limit be removed?

Comment: Have you signed in to the Early Adopter Program? Reference:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: I have paid GCP instance

Comment: I removed the "why this limit exist" part because it's a question that only Google could answer and it could make the question be closed as opinion based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increase the 6 minute execution limit in Google Apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971806/how-can-i-increase-the-6-minute-execution-limit-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: As @Rubén said, early adopters program could be the solution as it allows 30 minutes of execution time (actually first time I hear of this so must be very very recent) otherwise there is no way to remove the 6 minutes execution limit.